# XLSX excel (POI Java). No data appear on row and column

Tags: java, apache-poi, xlsx

Here's my code:

```
try {
        response.setContentType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename="
                + ReportID + ".xlsx");

        String excelFileName = "C:\\Test.xlsx";
        XSSFWorkbook w = new XSSFWorkbook();
        System.out.println("w: " + w);
        XSSFSheet s = w.createSheet(ReportID);
        System.out.println("s: " + s);

        // Report Title
        s.createRow(0).createCell(0).setCellValue(Title);
        System.out.println("Title: " + Title);

        // Populate the worksheet
        int _col_cnt = HeadersLabel.length;
        XSSFRow row = s.createRow(_col_cnt);
        System.out.println("HeadersLabel: " + _col_cnt);

        for (int c = 0; c < _col_cnt; c++) {
            // Construct the header row
            String _h = HeadersLabel[c];
            System.out.println("_h: " + _h);
            //XSSFRow row = s.createRow(0);

            if (_h != null) {
                XSSFCell hd = row.createCell(c);
                hd.setCellValue(_h);                    
            }       


            int r = 5;          
            for (Iterator iter = Cells.iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
                Object[] _o = (Object[]) iter.next();
                XSSFRow rowData = s.createRow(r);
                XSSFCell data = rowData.createCell(c);

                if (CellDataType[c].equals("STRING")
                        || CellDataType[c].equals("VARCHAR")) {
                    String _l = (String) _o[c];
                    if (_l != null) {
                        // Label label = new Label(c, r, (String) _o[c]);
                        //XSSFCell data = rowData.createCell(c);
                        data.setCellValue(_l);
                    }

                } else if (CellDataType[c].equals("DOUBLE")) {
                    Double _D = (Double) _o[c];
                    if (_D != null) {
                        // Number number = new Number(c, r,
                        // _D.doubleValue());
                        // s.addCell(number);
                        //XSSFCell data = rowData.createCell(c);
                        data.setCellValue(_D);
                    }

                } else if (CellDataType[c].equals("INTEGER")) {
                    Integer _I = (Integer) _o[c];
                    if (_I != null) {
                        // Number number = new Number(c, r,
                        // _I.doubleValue());
                        // s.addCell(number);
                        //XSSFCell data = rowData.createCell(c);
                        data.setCellValue(_I);

                    }
                } else if (CellDataType[c].equals("DATE")) {
                    Date _aDate = (Date) _o[c];
                    if (_aDate != null) {
                        // DateTime dateCell = new DateTime(c, r, _aDate,
                        // dateFormat);
                        // s.addCell(dateCell);
                        //XSSFCell data = rowData.createCell(c);
                        data.setCellValue(_aDate);
                    }
                } else if (CellDataType[c].equals("TIMESTAMP")) {
                    Timestamp _aTimestamp = (Timestamp) _o[c];
                    Date _aDate = Timestamp2Date(_aTimestamp);
                    if (_aDate != null) {
                        // DateTime dateCell = new DateTime(c, r, _aDate,
                        // dateFormat);
                        // s.addCell(dateCell);
                        //XSSFCell data = rowData.createCell(c);
                        data.setCellValue(_aDate);
                    }
                }
```

The XLSX excel did not manage to capture some data. The first two column is empty but there's suppose to be data appearing. Only the third column has the data.

What it looks like now: https://www.dropbox.com/s/2vfxsootyln6qq5/Capture3.JPG

What it suppose to be like: https://www.dropbox.com/s/d0yctgk4pywh140/Capture2.JPG

Comment: I have manage to edit the codes and solve the problem of my header title. But right now, I am still having problem with my data appearing on the first two column. (have updated the image link)

Answer (score 2):

When you are writing the cell content, for each cell iteration, you are creating new row, which actually removing your previous row, and so at the end, you are getting data on your last cell only. Following is your code.

```
for (Iterator iter = Cells.iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
            Object[] _o = (Object[]) iter.next();
            XSSFRow rowData = s.createRow(r);
            s.createRow(0).createCell(0).setCellValue(Title);
```

You need to call create row just once for each row before entering in this loop. Once the row is created you just need to create column, and that must be for each column of that row  It should be like following.

```
    XSSFRow rowData = s.createRow(r);
 for (Iterator iter = Cells.iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
            Object[] _o = (Object[]) iter.next();
            rowData..createCell(0).setCellValue(Title);
```

Please note it is my first reflection on your code, and I have not tried the same on my system. So just take it as a hint and correct the same wherever required and then check again.

Comment: Hi. 
Thank you! I will try it again tomorrow in the office.

I don't have such foundation for poi java and I am tasked to do this ><

Comment: @user3640070 to add to this answer, looking at your code, you do create a lot of cells and rows that seems to override each other. You should make sure to create your rows and cells once and only once.

Comment: @Sankumarsingh 
- The code is not working. After trying, my excel only prints out the title, heading for 3 column and only one data is being print out under the 3rd column. No heading and data for column 1 and 2. (it's similar to this, https://www.dropbox.com/s/lxmjbpv94wetfdu/Capture.JPG just that instead of having many data on 3r5d column, it only become one.)

Comment: I have manage to edit the codes and solve the problem of my header title. But right now, I am still having problem with my data appearing on the first two column. (have updated the image link). Do you mind helping?

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau how should I rewrite it? Sorry about that because I am really weak in coding :/